# bitwise OR in iOS

Tags: c, ios

```
enum {
   UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews            = 1 <<  0,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction      = 1 <<  1,
   UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState     = 1 <<  2,
   UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat                    = 1 <<  3,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse               = 1 <<  4,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration = 1 <<  5,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve    = 1 <<  6,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent      = 1 <<  7,
   UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews   = 1 <<  8,

   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,

   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    = 1 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   = 2 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          = 3 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        = 4 << 20,
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAnimationOptions;
```

What exactly means this expression: `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`.

Value of UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat is equal to 8(in bin 1000), UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse is equal to 16(in bin 10000). So expression `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` should generate as I think 16(bin 10000) -> UIViewAnimationOptionReverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` is known as a "mask".

If you have a variable of type `UIViewAnimationOptions`, say:

```
 UIViewAnimationOptions a;
```

you can apply the mask to it like this:

```
 bool b = a && (UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse)
```

to determine if `a` "contains" either flags. If

```
a == 0x0000001;
```

then

```
b == false;
```

if

```
a == 0x0101001;  //-- completely arbitrary mask
```

then

```
 b == true;
```

So you are not actually interested in what `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` evaluates to, but only in the result of logically and-ing a value of that type to the flags you are interested in checking.

Comment: ok, but consider this popular case where you have options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse (24)

Answer (score 3):

The operation `|` is defined by the truth table

```
   | 0 | 1  
---+---+---
 0 | 0 | 1
 1 | 1 | 1
```

that is, `x | y == 0` only if both `x == 0` and `y == 0`. The `|` operator works on all bits of a machine word at the same time. So

```
  001000   (8)
| 010000  (16)
  ------------
  011000  (24)
```

Comment: You have an extra `0` in your last operation =)

Comment: @Ed S. You can't have too many `0`es. You never know when you'll need one.

Comment: You can if they are in the wrong position as they were before your edit.  You had `10000 | 100000`, which was incorrect.

Comment: Although, erm... I don't see an edit... so maybe I misread.  I could have sworn...

Comment: @Ed S. Well spotted. IIRC, there is a "grace period", where you can edit your posts without those edits showing up. You are right, I corrected it after counting again.

Comment: Haha, ok, good to know I'm not losing my mind =D.  I knew it was a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

The bits are or'd:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat      = 1 << 3 = 8  = 01000 in binary
UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse = 1 << 4 = 16 = 10000 in binary

   01000
OR 10000
--------
   11000
```

11000 in binary is 16 + 8 = 24 - an integer with third and fourth bits set (counting from 0).

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
```

is equivalent to

```
01000
10000 |
```

the result of which is

```
11000
```

which is not `10000` as you had assumed.